# Making a border thick of a html table after every 2 rows

Tags: html, css

I have created a table with some contents, in that I have 12 rows and 2 columns. I want to display borders, but after every 4 rows, I want to set horizontal border thicker than normal. How to do that? Please help here.

Comment: please post the related code..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this selector

```
table tr:nth-of-type(4n) td {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
}
```

Explanation : We are first selecting `table` element here and than by using `:nth-of-type(4n)` we are selecting every 4th row in that table, and at last we select `td` element in that 4th row and apply styles to that. You can use `border-bottom`, `border-top` properties if you want to have borders on top and bottom or simply use `border` to have border on all sides of your `td` element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y68U/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y68U/1/) (CSS Normalized)

This way you don't have to declare any class..

HTML (If anyone requires)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: The above selector will select all the tables in your website, so better assign a class to your table and select that specific table you want to apply styles on, for example

```
table.class_name tr:nth-of-type(4n) td {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the css nth-child selector:

```
#your-table .table-row:nth-child(4n) {
    border-bottom-width: 4px;   
}
```