# Create a different table in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a table with few rows but with large columns where every 4th column's right boundary is 2 times as thick as the other boundaries.

Example:

```
|  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||
|  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||
|  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||  |  |  |  ||
```

Consider `||` as double width of `|`.

Comment: google `colspan` attribute. [See example](https://codepen.io/TombsTGMan/pen/zKYjOj)

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: .yourTableClass table td:nth-child(4){ width:10px}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a border thick of a html table after every 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623005/making-a-border-thick-of-a-html-table-after-every-2-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nth-child` css selector

```css
td{ border-right:1px solid #ccc}

td:nth-child(4n){
  border-right-width:10px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
  <td>Col 4</td>
  <td>Col 5</td>
  <td>Col 6</td>
  <td>Col 7</td>
  <td>Col 8</td>
  <td>Col 9</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
  <td>Col 4</td>
  <td>Col 5</td>
  <td>Col 6</td>
  <td>Col 7</td>
  <td>Col 8</td>
  <td>Col 9</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
  <td>Col 4</td>
  <td>Col 5</td>
  <td>Col 6</td>
  <td>Col 7</td>
  <td>Col 8</td>
  <td>Col 9</td>

</tr>
</table>
```